# How to make Pandas dataframe run on multiple cores?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multicore

I have around 5 million rows being processed in pandas dataframe & its taking about 45 minutes.There are multiple columns, data transformation involves copying some columns to new column, changing values in some as per given logic and many such transformations.
Since pandas runs only on one core at a time, my other nodes are remaining idle. How do i make pandas utilize all available nodes & reduce the total transformation time ?

Comment: Im not sure about pandas. But have you thought of trying pySpark. It gives similar capabilities to pandas and was made ti run distributed. So you can run you calculations on an EMR cluster in the cloud!

Comment: Take a loot at Dask, it is very similar for Pandas but support for multiple cores. https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/. Kr

Answer (score 1):

A package that parallelizes Pandas over multiple CPU cores is [modin](https://pypi.org/project/modin/). Read more about it at its [official documentation](https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) page.

The way to go ahead would be to use `ray` as the backend. It is installed via `pip` as follows:

```bash
pip install modin[ray]
```

In case you have a preference for `dask`, you can install it as:

```bash
pip install modin[dask]
```

To use the package, just change the import, and `~88 %` of the functions you need are available:

```py
import modin.pandas as pd
import numpy as np

frame_data = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(2**10, 2**8))
df = pd.DataFrame(frame_data)
```

Comment: A word of caution, though, not all tasks/operations on modin actually give the expected speedup. This may be due to how the aggregation works! Not sure though.